How do I write a JUnit test for the below code and not get a NullPointerException?
I'm trying to write the JUnit for the below code and kind of stuck.
public List<PartGEntity> getBEntityId(List<GBEntityDTO> gBEntities, BigInteger partId) {
    List<PartGEntity> partGEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(gBEntities)) {
        gBEntities.forEach(gBEntityDTO -> {
            PartGEntity partGEntity = createPartGEntity(
                    statClient.getBEntityByAnetId(gBEntityDTO.getAnetId()));
            partGEntity.setPartyId(partyId);
            partGEntityList.add(partGEntity);
        });
    }
    return partGEntityList;
}

I have written the below test for this one, but it's failing.
BEntityDTO bEntityByAnetId = new BEntityDTO();
bEntityByAnetId.setAnetId("5738");
bEntityByAnetId.setEffectiveDate(new Date());
when(statClient.getBEntityByAnetId("5738")).thenReturn(bEntityByAnetId);    
when(partGEntityDS.getBEntityId(newBEntityList,partId)).thenReturn(partGEntityList);

I'm mocking the statClient as above, but when executing the testcases, I get a NullPointerException at the below line:
createPartGEntity(statClient.getBEntityByAnetId(gBEntityDTO.getAnetId()));

While executing the statClient. I did a debug here as well. I tried to evaluate each of the expressions. While evaluating the expression, gBEntityDTO.getAnetId(), I get the proper result. However, while trying to evaluate this entire line, statClient.getBEntityByAnetId(gBEntityDTO.getAnetId()), I get a NullPointerException. I am not able to resolve this. As I have done the mocking above. I'm don't understand why the NullPointerException occurs.

what is gBEntityDTO? It is not set in your mock and not clear where it is used at all. Neither is your method createPartGEntity. So you state to have written a test for getBEntityId, but you don't test that method but rather you mock it and are testing something completely different.

@juwil, I have set the values for bEntityByAnetId like above (updated the request).Missed to include it previously.  But the evaluation of this line 'statClient.getBEntityByAnetId(gBEntityDTO.getAnetId())' in the original method is still throwing null.

Please provide a [mre], as it stands you're presenting incomplete fragments of code (e.g. you don't actually show that you're mocking statClient), and also provide the full exception stacktrace.
